# Global variable value assignment inside function

Tags: development

If i change the value of a global value inside a a function will that change apply to other functions or after the function ends ir resets to the default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change in the global will be visible to all functions that use it. If this is not what you want, make sure your variables are scoped properly to avoid local variables from polluting the globals.

Answer (score 0):

For example in JavaScript, Global variables belongs to Window object. So they can be access as window['variableName']. It can be understood from following code sample.

```
var a = "one";
alert(a); //output --> one
myFunction();

function myFunction(){
  var a = "two";
  alert(a) //output --> two

  alert(window['a']); // output --> one
  window['a'] = "three";   //edit global variable value inside a function
  alert(a); //output --> two
}
alert(a); //output --> three
```